# Are executables or applications signed in macOS?

Tags: macos, sign

This is a straightforward question that I was not able to determine with a bit of research.

In macOS, are *binaries* signed or are *applications* (e.g. *.app) signed? I have found evidence of the latter (and a tool called `codesign` that can check signatures and even show which files were modified), but am unsure of the former.

For example, are base user utilities (e.g. `cp`, `grep`, `ls`, etc) all signed? Or are they somehow bundled in with the `Terminal.app` that is itself signed? What about utilities that are not part of an `.app` bundle? Can they be individually signed? Where does this signature live?

In general, how does *signing* work in macOS and how is it enforced? Does the loader check and validate the signature, or does the kernel? It would seem the loader would also need a signature.

Comment: Explanations of the downvotes would be more helpful. I am not asking _how to sign_ something, I am asking _how it works_. The former is easier to find.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, and StackOverflow is for answering "a specific programming problem", which usually involves source code (an MCVE).  That's why the only answer you got was "RTFM", too.  You also appear to have done no research of your own: you don't say what you've read or tried, and the links provided to you (which you say you did not find) were literally the first two google hits for the phrase "macos code signing".

Comment: @Ssswift. I did research, but the question I am asking was not answered. My intent is not yet to learn _how_ things are signed, but _what_ is signed. Though the first few Google hits talk a great deal about how to use the signing infrastructure, I found little discussing the implementation of signing -- which is what I am asking here. If you take a few seconds to poke around you can find overwhelming evidence that applications and bundles can be signed. My question was can this signing infrastructure be used to sign individual binaries, not application archives. Your comment was not helpful.

Comment: sherrellbc: How can I be more helpful?  I tried to explain that the downvotes could be because this forum is for "specific programming questions", and this does not sound like such a question.  You keep hammering away on the specific aspect you're interested in, but have not explained how this question is relevant for this forum in the first place.

Comment: Since this program does not appear to be about programming, perhaps superuser.com would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

RTFM

Code Signing Guide
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Technical Note TN2206 / macOS Code Signing In Depth
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2206/_index.html

Comment: I do not write apps. I did not find that link when I was searching. There is a bit of good information there. The link is more about how to sign images, though. I am more interested in how it works. Thanks.

Comment: Well, a lot of the details of *how* it works are a secret, which is par for security frameworks. The less details the authors publish the less information hackers have to circumvent it. That said, you can infer a lot of what has to be signed and why from the guides that explain what you have to sign and how.

Comment: As for things like individual binaries, you *can* sign them. The system binaries are not signed because their distribution is signed and the installed copies are protected with SIP.